# Spring: object not being autowired, works fine in another class

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, autowired

I'm creating an util class, but the problem is that a service class is not being autowired.
The autowired class is also used elsewhere, so I just copied the autowire code.
And the package is being scanned.

```
public class X implements Y{
    @Autowired
    private Z z;

    public String getA(B b) {
        int a= Integer.parseInt(b);
        return z.getD(a);
    }

}
```

Does anyone have any idea why despite this z is still null?

Comment: how do you get an instance of `X`, on which to invoke `getA`?

Comment: did you add the @service or @component on class X?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forgot `@Component`

Answer (score 0):

The Class X should be declared in the context.

Comment: this is a comment, not an answer.